# How to create column in dataframe with list of headings affected by condition, apply a cap and then exclude not respecting condition headings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I'm struggling to solve this issue. Help would be very much appreciated.

Note: **bold** in the text refers to the columns i need to create.

I have a data set in which I count the values of the row that are different than nan, and it's represented in column [count]. In column **[incl_count]** i would like to have lists which identify the headings of the columns contributing to the count.
Next, I would like to have a limitation **[lim]** column in which I cannot have more than 3 counts. There is a cap of maximum 3. This means that the last columns to arrive to the counting cannot be considering and therefore excluded, being the exclusion saved in column **[excl]**

```
[index]     [A]   [B]   [C]    [D]    [E]    [F]  [count] [incl_count]    [lim]  [excl]
   ...
   ...
   ...

2020-01-01  nan    nan   nan   nan    nan    nan     0      []             0       []
2020-01-02 -0.01   nan   nan   nan    nan    nan     1      [A]            1       []
2020-01-03  0.02   nan   nan   nan    nan    nan     1      [A]            1       []
2020-01-04 -0.01   0.01  nan   nan    nan    nan     2      [A,B]          2       []
2020-01-05 -0.02  -0.04  0.02  nan    nan    nan     3      [A,B,C]        3       []
2020-01-06  nan    0.02  0.03  0.02   0.01   nan     4      [B,C,D,E]      3       [E]
2020-01-07  nan   -0.02  0.01  -0.01  0.03   0.01    5      [B,C,D,E,F]    3       [E,F]
2020-01-08  nan    nan  -0.02  0.05   -0.05  0.02    4      [C,D,E,F]      2       [E,F]
2020-01-09  nan    nan   nan   0.02   0.02   0.05    3      [D,E,F]        1       [E,F]
2020-01-10  nan    nan   nan    nan   nan    0.01    1      [F]            0       [F]
   ...
   ...
   ...
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit further the **lim** column? What do you mean by "last column**s** to arrive"? For example, take the penultimate row, why would we exluce E,F and not just F?

Comment: Hello. The limit it's just a cap so that we are not allowed to consider more than 3 simultaneous open positions in the same date. The 4 and 5's in the count column are transformed into 3, as this is the cap. In the penultimate row the [E] needs to be excluded because once a position is excluded in the first date it cannot be longer considered in a later date. (this is why E and F are always excluded from the renaming dates)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

non_value_columns = ["index", "incl_count", "excl", "lim", "count"]
max_lim = 3
entries = []
df = pd.read_excel('your.xlsx')
for entry in df:
    if entry not in non_value_columns:
        print(entry)
        entries.append(entry)

indexes = df['index'].tolist()

i = 0
cur_excludes = []
for index in indexes:
    c = 0
    incl = []
    excl = []
    for entry in entries:
        if not np.isnan(df[entry].tolist()[i]):
            incl.append(entry)
            c += 1
            if max_lim < c or entry in cur_excludes:
                c -= 1
                excl.append(entry)
                cur_excludes.append(entry)
    df.loc[i, 'lim'] = str(c)
    df.loc[i, 'incl_count'] = str(incl)
    df.loc[i, 'excl'] = str(excl)
    i += 1
df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

Edit: Changed code so it would loop through all the different columns. Made an array where you can state the columns that are nonvalue columns, make sure you extend it if you add columns that you do not want to check it is name-based so just add the name of the column. Also made a variable where you can state your limit. Hope this works tell me if anything goes wrong!

Comment: hello Rutger. Thank you for taking the time to answer the question with a possible solution. Unfortunately, I'm not sure if this solution will indeed help me. The example I gave above it was just for demonstration proposes, as I will need to use this solution for a considerable bigger data set. It's will not be feasible to create if conditions for each of the hundreds of columns the data set has. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Edited it so now it does not need a different if for each column, make sure you add the nonvalue columns and set the right limit.

Comment: Hello FJ35 I changed the code good you take a look at it if this is what you need?